# Print rows based on criteria using unix

Tags: unix, awk, rows, criteria, csv

I have a .tsv file that looks like this:

```
Ccrux.01.003887.832-13315   523 SMART   411 444 180.0   IPR019734   GO:0005515
Ccrux.01.003887.832-13315   523 SMART   339 372 0.035   IPR019734   
Ccrux.01.003887.832-13315   523 SMART   445 478 460.0   TIPR019734  
Ccrux.01.003887.832-13315   523 SMART   220 252 53.0    IPR019734   GO:0005515
Ccrux.01.003887.832-13315   523 SMART   296 338 17.0    IPR019734   GO:0005515
Ccrux.01.003887.832-13315   523 SMART   183 216 0.0069  IPR019734   
Ccrux.01.003887.832-13315   523 SMART   258 291 29.0    IPR019734   GO:0005515
```

I want to select only the rows containing GO:XXXXXXX and print only columns 6 and 8 (the criteria one) in a new file. So the new file should look like this:

```
180.0   GO:0005515
53.0    GO:0005515
17.0    GO:0005515
29.0    GO:0005515
```

I tried:

```
awk -F"\t" '$8 == GO { print $6"\t"$8 }' file.in > file.out
```

But my file.out only contains column 6 and that's it.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The easy way out is to prepend: 
    `cat file.tsv |grep GO |`
Edit: I see that may not be the whole problem though... looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

awk can handle tabs by default. This should do

```
awk '$8 ~ /GO/ {print $6 "\t" $8}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... though a purely awk answer would probably be better.

```
cat /tmp/file|grep GO |awk '{print $6 "\t" $8}'
180.0   GO:0005515
53.0    GO:0005515
17.0    GO:0005515
29.0    GO:0005515
```